# Restful web API with static context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, polling, performancecounter

I am writing a tool where you can see the PerfomanceCounter.NextValue() of CPU or memory in Web. Now I have a rest web api and angular in the frontend where the chart is drawn. I thought about Websockets but I think it is better to use polling from the frontend. But rest api methods should be independend from objects, and the performancecounter class always takes lot of time for initialization.

I have already tried to initialize the performancecounter every time a get request is coming but that consumes very much time and the response time is really bad. And I want to see the live chart of maybe the cpu in every second a new value.

Do you have any ideas how to avoid initializing every time?

Comment: Could you provide the code (here or in a jsFiddle) to show us what you have tried already? That way it will be easier to help.

Comment: you can make a singleton class with private constructor where you can initialize your performancecounter. no new instance will be made each time so you have the benefit you expected. some concurrency problems is there to avoid so read more about it if you want thread safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Lazy static initialization, PerformanceCounter object is tread safe.

For example:

```
public static Lazy<PerformcanceCounter> Counter= new Lazy<PerformcanceCounter>(() =>{

    return new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName, false);
});
```

And then use it in code like:

```
Counter.Value.Next();
```

The initialization will run only once, on the first access to the Lazy object.

Another technique is to [use static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors).
The only different is that type constructor will run of first access to the type.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Excactly what i need!